# rotating and cropping a bitmap accurately and effiently in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm writing an android application.By using it,a user can crop the bitmap image.But I want to add more function,that is to rotate the image before cropping.
I followed the below steps to accomplish this purpose.

1. built a custom view.
2. initialized `BitmapDrawable()` and a cropping rectangle(`Rect()`) [the rectangle determines where to cop in the bitmap]
3. override `onTouch(MotionEvent)` method for two functions

   - a. user can move the bitmap over the screen
   - b. user can transform the cropping rectangle
4. override `onDraw(Canvas)` method to update the screen.This code is for showing bitmap.

   ```
   bitmap_drawable.draw(canvas,_bitmap_paint);
   ```
5. #### Problem:1

   This step ,that I don't know how to do, is to show a rotated  properly. I used this code to rotate the canvas in the `onDraw(Canvas)` method.

   ```
   canvas.rotate(_angle);
   ```

   But it makes all the things on the screen (including the  cropping rectangle) to rotate.

   #### Question:2

   Is it a wise way to initialize my own `Canvas()` object to draw the bitmap on?

   #### Note:

   Here,the rotation that I want,is very accurate up to 1 degree and is performed by two-finger rotation gesture so that performance is very important and the following code(using matrix) is bad.

   ```
   Matrix mat = new Matrix();

   mat.preRotate(_degree, _one_finger_x, _one_finger_y);

   Bitmap _new_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_old_bitmap, 0, 0, bmWidth, bmHeight, mat, true);
   ```

   Therefore,I think initializing a separate `Canvas()` and using `canvas.rotate(_degree)` is very appropriate.However,this makes controlling touch events quite difficult.Any ideas?Please help.
6. #### Problem:2

   Suppose that I can now rotate the bitmap separately from all objects,i.e. the cropping rectangle,etc.This step is to crop the bitmap and show the cropped result to the user efficiently.When rotate function is not included, I simply copy the color bytes within the cropping rectangle on the old bitmap as follow.

   ```
   Bitmap _new_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( _old_bitmap, _cropRectx, _cropRecty, _cropRectWidth, _cropRectHeight, null);
   ```

   But here,from a rotated bitmap, how can I clone the color bytes through a crossing crop rectangle?

   #### Question:2

   How can I crop a rotated bitmap?

Comment: The question may be too long,but it contains only two questions:(i)what is the best way for displaying a rotated bitmap up to 1 rotating degree? (ii)how to crop a rotated bitmap?Any answer?please help.